# How do I add a link to a file in PdfSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I can't seem to get PdfSharp to show a picture for this annotation. It doesn't have the PdfAnnotation.Icon property, so I can't set that.

```
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 10);
PdfPage page = wDoc.Parent.Page;
XGraphics gfx = wDoc.Parent.gfx;
XRect rec = gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(new XRect(new XPoint(30, 60), new XSize(30, 30)));
PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(rec);
PdfLinkAnnotation link = PdfLinkAnnotation.CreateFileLink(rect, wDoc.FileLocation);
gfx.DrawString("These files were attached:", font, XBrushes.Black, 30, 50, XStringFormat.Default);

link.Rectangle = new PdfRectangle(rec);
page.Annotations.Add(link);
```

I've gotten it that far, and the annotation DOES exist, except it's a blank box! How do I go about making it say something, or even just show a picture?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use page.AddWebLink(AREArect) and then add the text area with gfx.drawstring(AREArect)

Answer (score 4):

sample code for [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) usage:

```
...
PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfReader.Open(myUri.LocalPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
PdfDocument pdfNewDoc = new PdfDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.Pages.Count; i++)
{
   PdfPage page = pdfNewDoc.AddPage(pdfDoc.Pages[i]);
   XFont fontNormal = new XFont("Calibri", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);    
   XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
   var xrect = new XRect(240, 395, 300, 20);
   var rect = gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(xrect);
   var pdfrect = new PdfRectangle(rect);

   //file link
   page.AddFileLink(pdfrect, myUri.LocalPath);
   //web link
   //page.AddWebLink(pdfrect, myUri.AbsoluteUri);


   gfx.DrawString("MyFileName", fontNormal, XBrushes.Black, xrect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
}
pdfNewDoc.Save(myDestinationUri.LocalPath + "MyNewPdfFile.pdf");
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with class PdfLinkAnnotation.
You can use page.AddDocumentLink, page.AddWebLink, and page.AddFileLink to create links.
If you use these methods, you can draw the icon as an image.